# How to improve query performance n+1

Tags: django

I have the following:

```
#models:py    
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Comment(models.Model):
    book = ForeignKey(book)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

#views.py
class AuthorBookComment(ListView):
    model = Author
    paginate_by = 5
    template = “template.html”

#template.html  
{% for author in object_list %}
    <h2>{{ author.name }}</h2>
    {% for book in author.book_set.all %}
        <h3>{{book.title}}</h3>
        {% for comment in book.comment_set.all %}
            {{comment.title}}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<<pagination code>>
```

The idea is to display all authors and their books and comments (if such exist).

The challenges:
1.      Performance degradation as data volumes increase (number of sql requests = n+1).
2.      Pagination on Author set vs. Author + Book + Comment set.

Question:  How can the above be improved/optimised?

I have tried various versions of select_related() and prefetch_related(). Results below, but still not sufficiently performant + large data sets are returned. Is there a better way?

Queries, TimeMs: Queryset
230, 106: Author.objects.all()
229, 105: Author.objects.all().prefetch_related(book_set').all()
179, 88: Author.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_set__comment_set').all()

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/#retrieve-everything-at-once-if-you-know-you-will-need-it

Comment: I have tried various versions of select_related() and prefetch_related().  Results below, but still not sufficiently performant + large data sets are returned.  Is there a better way? 
Queries, TimeMs: Queryset

230, 106: Author.objects.all()

229, 105: Author.objects.all().prefetch_related(book_set').all()

179, 88:  Author.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_set__comment_set').all()

Comment: The last query should get you down to 3 or 4 queries, so you'd have to find out where the other 175 come from (using Django Debug Toolbar for example).

Answer (score 0):

You should always eager load data in these situations using [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/%E2%80%A6) or [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).